# Find difference between two calculated groups?

Tags: tableau-api

I have dummy HR data, and I want to color format via a map the difference in median salary based on groupings of birth year.

I have a quick calc field to separate them into birth year groups:

```
IF DATE([Date of Birth]) >=#1976# THEN "Group 1"
ELSE "Group 2"
END
```

Now I want to find the difference between the median salaries for those two groups, but I want to conditionally format them via a map to see where the median salary remained similar or differed a lot.

For instance: `Median(Group 1([salary])-Median(Group 2([salary])` would give me a `+/- difference` and then I'd like that to be colored via a gradient and then outlines via state level detail.

This is probably so easy, but I can't think of how to do it via those groups. Would this be a LOD calc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a calc to return the salary for rows in group 1, and null otherwise. Call it say, **Old_Folks_Salary**, defined something like `if Year([Birth Date]) < 1976 then [Salary] end` (If the condition in the if statement is not satisfied, and there is no else clause, the expression returns null.) Define a similar field for the youngsters.

The trick to know is that aggregation functions, like Median, silently ignore null values. It’s as if the null values don’t even exist. So ... You can now express your aggregate calculation as

`Median([Old Folks Salary]) - Median([Young Folks Salary])`

For extra credit, you can replace the hard coded threshold of 1976 with a parameter, and look for more politically acceptable field names.